# Trying to have plot a graph on my PyQt5 Gui but cannot get it to show

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyqt5

I'm trying to build a small GUI with PyQt5 and have a visualization tab which shows a tab. I have done a little research and wanted to display a simple plot to get started but I couldn't get it to show on the GUI.

I used Qt designer for the GUI layout.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QVBoxLayout, QAction, QFileDialog,QApplication, QMainWindow
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.figure import Figure

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(789, 640)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(789, 599))
        self.centralwidget.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(789, 599))
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.widget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.widget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 761, 531))
        self.widget.setObjectName("widget")
        self.gridLayoutWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.widget)
        self.gridLayoutWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(-1, -1, 761, 531))
        self.gridLayoutWidget.setObjectName("gridLayoutWidget")
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.gridLayout.setSizeConstraint(QtWidgets.QLayout.SetDefaultConstraint)
        self.gridLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.frame = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.frame.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.frame.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.frame.setObjectName("frame")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.frame, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 789, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        self.menuShow_Plot = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.menubar)
        self.menuShow_Plot.setObjectName("menuShow_Plot")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)
        self.actionShow_Plot = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionShow_Plot.setObjectName("actionShow_Plot")
        self.menuShow_Plot.addAction(self.actionShow_Plot)
        self.menubar.addAction(self.menuShow_Plot.menuAction())

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.menuShow_Plot.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Menu"))
        self.actionShow_Plot.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Show Plot"))
```

Then added this to show a simple plot:

```
class Sheet(Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        super().setupUi(MainWindow)
        self.sc = myCanvas()
        self.l=QVBoxLayout(self.frame)
        self.l.addWidget(self.sc)
        self.ToolBar()
    
    def Toolbar(self):
        
        self.actionShow_Plot.triggered.connect(self.Plot)
        

    def Plot(self):
        x=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
        y=[2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20]
        
        self.sc.plot(x,y)
    

class myCanvas(FigureCanvas):
    def __init__(self):    
        self.fig = Figure()
        FigureCanvas.__init__(self,self.fig)
    
    def plot(self,x,y):
        self.fig.clear()
        self.ax = self.fig.add_subplot(111)
        self.ax.plot(x[1:],y[1:])
        self.draw


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Whenever I click the 'show plot' on the menu bar nothing happens. How do I get this to work? Because I think I've followed all the instructions from the tutorials I've seen. Thanks.

Comment: TYPO: change `self.draw` to `self.draw()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other than the typo @eyllanesc pointed out, your are not using your class `Sheet` that's one of the main reason why it is not working.

Here is an fixed example:

```py
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QVBoxLayout, QAction, QFileDialog, QApplication, QMainWindow
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib.artist import Artist


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(789, 640)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(789, 599))
        self.centralwidget.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(789, 599))
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")

        self.widget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.widget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 761, 531))
        self.widget.setObjectName("widget")

        self.gridLayoutWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.widget)
        self.gridLayoutWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(-1, -1, 761, 531))
        self.gridLayoutWidget.setObjectName("gridLayoutWidget")

        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.gridLayout.setSizeConstraint(
            QtWidgets.QLayout.SetDefaultConstraint)
        self.gridLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")

        self.frame = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.frame.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.frame.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.frame.setObjectName("frame")

        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.frame, 0, 0, 1, 1)

        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 789, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")

        self.menuShow_Plot = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.menubar)
        self.menuShow_Plot.setObjectName("menuShow_Plot")

        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")

        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.actionShow_Plot = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionShow_Plot.setObjectName("actionShow_Plot")
        self.menuShow_Plot.addAction(self.actionShow_Plot)

        self.menubar.addAction(self.menuShow_Plot.menuAction())

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.menuShow_Plot.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Menu"))
        self.actionShow_Plot.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Show Plot"))


class Sheet(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.setUpCanvasUi()
        self.connectSingalSlots()

    def setUpCanvasUi(self):
        self.sc = myCanvas()
        self.l = QVBoxLayout(self.ui.frame)
        self.l.addWidget(self.sc)
        self.ui.centralwidget.setLayout(self.l)

    def connectSingalSlots(self):
        self.ui.actionShow_Plot.triggered.connect(self.Plot)

    def Plot(self):
        print("get here")
        x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
        y = [2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20]

        self.sc.plot(x, y)


class myCanvas(FigureCanvas):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.fig = Figure()

        super(myCanvas, self).__init__(self.fig, *args, **kwargs)

    def plot(self, x, y):
        self.fig.clear()
        self.ax = self.fig.add_subplot(111)
        self.ax.plot(x[1:], y[1:])
        self.draw()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = Sheet()
    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

FYI: You should better take a look at [this tutorial](https://realpython.com/qt-designer-python/).

Comment: Thank you. I still have a major problem with inheritance and parent classes. Your solution worked.